# Why I am not receiving anything from the JS client (as Chrome Extension)?

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code

**Introduction**

I am learning from JS (after messing up with Java for a bit) and I stumbled upon sockets in javascript.

**Problem**

I've made a python server which is listening, then I loaded the JS extension to Chrome but the server does not get any message. Where I did wrong or what I am missing?

**manifest.Json (maybe it's relevant as I couldn't do this .js as "background")**

```
 {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Server-Test-Ext",
"version": "0.1",

"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["socket.js", "client.js"]


}]


}
```

**client.js ( example from the Socket.io website)**

```
var socket = new io.Socket();

socket.connect('https://localhost:8080');   

socket.on('connect', function(){
    // connected!
  });
  socket.on('message', function(msg){
      // message coming
  });
socket.send('Hello world!');
```

**server.py**

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8080

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn: 
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

The server creates successfully the tcp (You can see that by typing on the CMD netstat -an))

Notes:

```
- I am using Visual Studio Code (cool text editor, still learning it)
- I am new to the subject (self-taught)
```

My expectation was to receive the message on the python server, which is running before the ext. Obviously.

Thanks for the interest in this question.

Comment: var socket = new io.Socket(); shouldn't you specify target ip and port here also ?

Comment: I only get errors when I looked it up on Chrome. Such as not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to declare socket permission to your manifest.js.

details:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sockets